# Best way to store passwords?

Tags: c#, mongodb, authentication, password-protection, password-encryption

I'm trying to study how to safely store users (username and password) in my database.

From what I've gathered on my research, the safest way to store a password is:

- Generate Salt
- Concat Salt on the password
- Hash the concatenated result into SHA-256
- Iterate on it (should be 640.000 iterations if I got it right, but I'm not sure)

I found the class `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` which allows me to do that, but now I'm not sure how to store all the data in my database, my question is how am I going to do a login if the hashed password is always different?

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` generates a key, but I'm pretty sure that I should not save the key in the database, I don't know what do :(

For now this is what I wrote/gathered:

```
    public static byte[] GetSalt(int maximumLenght)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[maximumLenght];

        using (var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        }

        return salt;
    }
    public byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(byte[] password, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] concatenatedSalt = new byte[salt.Length + password.Length];
        concatenatedSalt = salt.Concat(password).ToArray();

        return settings.HashAlgorithmType.ComputeHash(concatenatedSalt);
    }

    public static byte[] HashPassword(byte[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations)
    {
        using (var rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations))
        {
            //dunno to do with that
            return rfc2898.GetBytes(32);
        }
    }
```

I should store the iteration count, salt and the hash? It is safe to do that?

Comment: You should store only the salt and the hash in the database.

Comment: @KlausGütter I edited just now, cause I read that I should store the iterations, the salt, and the hashed password, but after that, if they request me a Login action, how am I gonna know if the two passwords are the same? Do I have to get the iterations and the salt and do the reverse to see if the two passwords match?

Comment: Hint: a hashing algorithm will give you the same result every time for the same input.

Comment: @Llama yeah true, that's why I concatenate salt on the password, but how do I match two passwords? I store the salt and the iterations and after I do the reverse to see if they match?

Comment: It's not possible to do the reverse. A hash is a one-way operation. You can do the same set of operations (i.e. apply the same salt, iterate the same number of times) on a different input and compare hashes though.

Comment: The hashed password should contain the whole parameters to produce the same hash from the same password. Then hash the password which you want to check and compare the result with the hashed password

Comment: @Llama uh ok, and is safe to store the salt and the iterations in the DB, if someone has access can easily generate them no?

Comment: @SirRufo ok, but the salt is always different, so I should first get the salt and the iterations, and then compare them?

Comment: See how Microsoft handles it https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Crypto.cs

Comment: @ZeroBrush you have a hashed password and the plain password (which you want to check). only the hashed password has salt and iteration. And you want to compare those to which, themself?

Comment: I think you're perhaps misunderstanding what you're aiming to protect against here. Using a salt means that if two users have the password "password" then they will still have different hashes. This stops attackers from having a dictionary of known passwords to known hashes and simply looking up the password from the hash in your database. Having multiple iterations increases the time complexity when computing the hash. While it doesn't have a perceivable slowdown, it can really slow down brute force attempts. You can also use a secret "pepper" which only the server knows, not the database.

Comment: @Llama not only two users, each time when you hash the password "password" you will recieve a different result :o)

Comment: @SirRufo Isn't that essentially what I said? It stops things like the Adobe attack where each user with the same password had the same encrypted (not even hashed) password, and the attackers were able to correlate them using password hints from all of the users with the same password.

Comment: @SirRufo yeah, I'm trying to do a Login, so I have the plain password (from the form) and the "seasoned" hashed password (from the db), how can I check if the password inserted is the same in the db, i mean the literal steps to do it. Use the salt and the iteration of the hashed password on the plain password and check if they match?

Comment: @LLama *... if **two users** have the password "password" ...* can mislead to "ah, same user same hash from password" - not more

Comment: @ZeroBrush Literal steps? 1) Don't generate a random salt, but use the same salt as you used to hash the actual password. 2) Use the same number of iterations as you used to hash the actual password. 3) Hash the password provided on the login form using the info from 1 & 2 and the same algorithm as you used for the actual password. 4) Compare the resulting hash with the one stored in the database. If they matched, it's the same password.

Comment: @Llama ok got it, I really thank you, I'm sorry if was frustrating.

Comment: It's also quite common to hash a combined value of username and password. By this you get a different hash value even if two user have the same password by coincidence.

Comment: OWASP has some great resources along  these topics, for example, [this](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html).